# Jetpack Compose DropdownMenu overlaps keyboard

Tags: drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I want to build a searchable DropDownMenu with Jetpack Compose and Material3.
The problem is, that the DropDownItems overlap the Keyboard. I think the selected DropDownMenuItem should scroll up, but I don't know how to achieve it.

screenshot of the behavior:
[image: screenshot of the behavior]

Here is my sample Code. How can I solve this?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DropDown() {
    var dropDownEntries = (1..20)
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val icon = painterResource(com.google.android.material.R.drawable.mtrl_ic_arrow_drop_down)
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    isExpanded = it.isFocused
                    if (!it.isFocused) {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    }
                },
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {
                isExpanded = true
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                },
            ),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            singleLine = true,
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(icon, "contentDescription", Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
                    if (!isExpanded) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                }))
            },
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .width(328.dp)
                .requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 168.dp),
            properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
            expanded = isExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { },
        ) {
            dropDownEntries.forEach { entry ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = entry.toString()) },
                    onClick = {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
) {
    Column {
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
        DropDown()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement a combo-box with Material3 you should use `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ExposedDropdownMenuBox(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1))).

Here is your source code modified accordingly. Note the `menuAnchor` modifier on the text field.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun DropDown() {
    val dropDownEntries = (1..20)
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onExpandedChange = { isExpanded = it },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .menuAnchor()
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {
                isExpanded = true
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    isExpanded = false
                },
            ),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            singleLine = true,
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = isExpanded) },
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .width(328.dp)
                .requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 168.dp),
            expanded = isExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false },
        ) {
            dropDownEntries.forEach { entry ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = entry.toString()) },
                    onClick = {
                        isExpanded = false
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks al lot for your help. It works great in my Scenario. But I work for a company and so I try to avoid ***ExperimentalMaterial3Api***. Is there a solution without the Experimental stuff?

Comment: @KingKarl There probably is, but i don't have a ready solution. Why bother about the Experimental status though, if it works? If it's ever removed, which i highly doubt, then you'll have to figure it out. Unless it's a company policy or something of course.